# Meteor lose scrollbar when i add item

Tags: meteor

when i add item to a list

the page rerender

but the scrollbar lose (which mean I can't see other parts of the page)

before I add item:

[image]

after I add item:

[image]

add item(js):

```
function resetForm () {
    form.reset();
    $("#goodImgPreview").attr('src', "");
    $('#addGoodModal').modal('hide');
}
uploadFile.read(file, function(err, upf) {
    // 展示 上传进度条
    Session.set('createGoodModalContentOnUpload', true);
    Meteor.call("upload", upf, function(err, fileId) {
        if (!err) {
            good.fileId = fileId;
            goodsCollection.insert(good);
            resetForm();
            Session.set('createGoodModalContentOnUpload', false);
        } else {
            Session.set('createGoodModalContentOnUpload', false);
        } 
    });
});
```

display list(html):

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each goodList}}
        {{> goodEdit}}
    {{/each}}
</div>


<template name="goodEdit">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="/uploadDir/{{owner}}/{{fileId}}" alt="" width="160" height="160">
        <label for="">{{name}}</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

display list(js):

```
Template.shopEditGoods.goodList = function() {
    return goodsCollection.find({shopId: Session.get('shopId')});
}
```

the router:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('shopCreate', {path: '/shopCreate/'});

    this.route('shopEditBasic', {
    path: '/shop/edit/:_id/basic/',
        layoutTemplate: 'shopEditLayout',
        waitOn: function() {
            Session.set('shopId', this.params._id);
            Session.set('shopEditSideNav', 'shopEditBasic')
            return Meteor.subscribe('shop', this.params._id);
        }
    });

    this.route('shopEditGoods', {
        path: '/shop/edit/:_id/goods/',
        layoutTemplate: 'shopEditLayout',
        waitOn: function() {
            Session.set('shopId', this.params._id);
            Session.set('shopEditSideNav', 'shopEditGoods')
            Meteor.subscribe('usergoods');
            return Meteor.subscribe('shop', this.params._id);
        }
    });

    this.route('shopEditPrices', {
        path: '/shop/edit/:_id/prices/',
        layoutTemplate: 'shopEditLayout',
        waitOn: function() {
            Session.set('shopId', this.params._id);
            Session.set('shopEditSideNav', 'shopEditPrices')
            Meteor.subscribe('usergoods');
            return Meteor.subscribe('shop', this.params._id);
        }
    });
});
```

===================================

I found a solution: add `html { overflow: scroll; }` to css file
but i  still don't know why it happen

Comment: The screenshots are good for illustration but you need to post some code that is relevant, e.g. the template and the items source.

Comment: @Tobold so funny comment :)

Comment: ye, I add it @Tobold  I just not sure what the accuracy position of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not provided any html. In the div container containing all this, you could use something like:

`overflow-y: scoll`

in your css to force the scroll bars on.